# UIPrintInteractionController Printingitems - Dismisses

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I have used this function for printing one PDF with success :

```
-(void)printPDF{

    NSString* fileName = @"Certificate.PDF";

    NSArray *arrayPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                        NSDocumentDirectory,
                                        NSUserDomainMask,
                                        YES);
    NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];


    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) NSLog(@"Print error: %@", error);
    };

    NSData *pdfData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:pdfFileName];

    printController.printingItem = pdfData;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [printController presentFromRect:self.btnPrint.frame inView:self.btnPrint.superview
                                animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    } else {
        [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }

}
```

When I want to print several PDF's I have put into an array (Certificates). The printController dialog dismisses before I get to choose a printer, and i get the following error.
"Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!"

Do I need to use some delgate method for the printcontroller, or what is the catch ?

This is my attempt for printing several PDF documents.

```
-(void)printAllPDF{

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) NSLog(@"Print error: %@", error);

    };

    printController.printingItems = certificates;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [printController presentFromRect:self.btnPrintAll.frame inView:self.btnPrintAll.superview
                                animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

    } else {
        [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad....I should have spent some more time debugging.

I was actually calling PrintPDF in my "Array loop"...
Ups...sorry :-(

```
- (IBAction)fcPrintAllBtn:(UIButton *)sender {

    [certificates removeAllObjects];

    for (Paxtype *pax in paxArray) {
        [self createPDFWithPax:pax Balloon:self.edtFlightBalloon.text Landing:self.edtLandingSite.text Date:self.edtFlightDate.text Gender:pax.sBookGender PaxTitle:self.edtPaxTitle.text Start:self.edtLaunchSite.text Speed:self.edtMaxSpeed.text Altitude:self.edtMaxAlt.text
                      Distance:self.edtDistance.text];
        NSString* fileName = @"Certificate.PDF";

        NSArray *arrayPaths =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                            NSDocumentDirectory,
                                            NSUserDomainMask,
                                            YES);
        NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSData *pdfData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:pdfFileName];

        [certificates addObject:pdfData];

        [self printAllPDF];   <-----This should not be here !!!

    }

    [self printAllPDF];   <-----But here !!

    NSLog(@"Certificates %i", certificates.count); 
}
```